# Firebase right way to trigger something dynamically

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, triggers, google-cloud-functions

Let me first describe you what I'm trying to do with one example:

```
- Players join a game (it's a web turn-based app/game with firebase/angular)
- When they are ready they have 30 seconds to choose a character
- Then player 1 has 30 sec to end his turn
- Then player 2 has 30 sec to end his turn
- ...
```

It's a little turn-based game and I'm having difficulties to end a turn. I thought about using cron or setInterval on a cloud function but setInterval isn't recommended (costly) and cron isn't exactly what I'm looking for (I don't want to trigger something everyday...). I saw this informations on two similars topics:

[setInterval on firebase instead of using cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685079/setinterval-on-firebase-instead-of-using-cron) && [Cloud Functions for Firebase trigger on time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time)

What should be the right way to do that (end a turn based on a time to increment the "state" of the game) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval in client-side js. Running setInterval in the browser is the correct way to perform some action after a pre-determined interval of time in javascript. setInterval does not work on cloud functions, but you don't need them there.

Psuedo code goes like:

1. Start player's turn by saving the current time
2. setInterval to start time + interval
3. 30 seconds later your setInterval callback executes where you can update the game state
4. Rinse and repeat

Comment: I already thought about doing that but as you said: it's client-side, and it's not the client's job to do that. But I think I'll use this solution if there is no way to do that on server side, thank's for your answer !

Comment: You can execute this logic on the client, but verify it in a cloud function or whatever backend you have. When the game state changes, have a function watching that data, which checks that each player's turn is only as long as the interval. This can help identify if something's not right with your clients.